# Maven project in Eclipse fails to build setting Maven Home

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run a program but I am unable bevause I keep getting this error. It's driving me nuts! I think it has to do with incorrectly setting my Maven Home but I am unsure, can anybody help me here? Has anybody encountered a similar problem? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
2/13 KB   4/20 KB   
2/13 KB   4/20 KB   
6/13 KB   4/20 KB   
6/13 KB   6/20 KB   
6/13 KB   10/20 KB   
10/13 KB   10/20 KB   
10/13 KB   14/20 KB   
13/13 KB   14/20 KB   
13/13 KB   18/20 KB   
13/13 KB   20/20 KB   

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 16.4 KB/sec)

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 25.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.337 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-15T16:21:06-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix ' compile exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/miqbal2/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

**mvn help:effective-pom OUTPUT:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.intuit.discovery.moneyfinder.nodeserver:APITestingNodeServer:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.3.3 @ line 99, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building APITestingNodeServer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom (default-cli) @ APITestingNodeServer ---
[INFO] 
Effective POMs, after inheritance, interpolation, and profiles are applied:

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2014-09-15T04:33:11                  -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'com.intuit.discovery.moneyfinder.nodeserver:APITestingNodeServer:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.discovery.moneyfinder.nodeserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>APITestingNodeServer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>API testing REST services for money finder</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
      <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target</directory>
    <finalName>APITestingNodeServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/miqbal2/Desktop/Discovery/APITestingNodeServer/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.770 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-15T16:33:11-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: post your `mvn help:effective-pom` 's output

Comment: What command are you executing? It looks like you are trying to use the maven-exec-plugin (based on the `compile exec` part of the error message) but you haven't defined it in your pom? What output does `mvn -version` give?